# create rest api for custom sugarcrm module to upload files

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created a module using module builder. Now, I am using REST API to create the custom module records. When I create a module with rest api almost all fields are affected(rest values are assigned), except file. I do not know how to upload file to server.
I have used set_entry to create module. set_note_attachment and set_document_revsion is only for uploading and creating document and note instances. Is there are any way to uplload custom module files to server
Thanks

Comment: What version of SugarCRM and the REST API are you using?

Comment: Sugarcrm 6.5 community edition