# How to create customer rest api for upload file in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I am using sugarcrm comunity edition 6.5. I have create a module for file upload. I have tried to create a record and upload files to the module using rest api. Record is created successfully. But the problem is it is not uploading files to module. Where can I found information for creating custom rest api to upload file? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create rest api for custom sugarcrm module to upload files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654104/create-rest-api-for-custom-sugarcrm-module-to-upload-files)